# Proguard in a gradle multiproject build setup

Tags: java, android, gradle, proguard

I have a gradle multiproject build setup in which each (sub-)project has its own specific proguard configuration file (*.pro). Within this multiproject build I can build a JavaFX and an Android application as target. Both of them I like to obfuscate with a configuration based on the collected proguard files of the depending projects.

My problem is the collecting of all necessary proguard files before the start of the obfuscation. Here is a basic visualization of my dependencies:

> LibCore (libcore.pro) (plain java project)
>
> \ -> LibDesktop (libdesktop.pro) (java project with dependencies to
>   JavaFX)
>
> \ ---> AppDesktop (appdesktop.pro)
>
> \ --> LibAndroid (libandroid.pro) (android library project)
>
> \ --> AppAndroid (appandroid.pro) (android application project)

If a like to obfuscate the AppAndroid project I need to collect the ProGuard files libcore.pro, libandroid.pro and appandroid.pro. Right now, I use following android-gradle code:

```
 proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                file('.' + '/' + 'appandroid.pro'),
                project(':LibAndroid').file('libandroid.pro'),
                project(':LibCore').file('libcore.pro'),
```

Because my project has significantly more subprojects I like to do this automatically based on the dependency structure.

Does anyone of you have an idea to solve this? Thanks in advance!